# Adding find condition to all Active Record Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find, conditional-statements

Is there anyway to add a find condition to all Active record models?

that is I would like this query

```
ExampleModel.find :all, :conditions=> ["status = ?", "active"]
```

to behave the same way as

```
ExampleModel.find :all
```

in every model

Thanks!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002313):

```
class ExampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => ["status = ?", "active"]
end
```

If you want to use this in all your models, you can either subclass `ActiveRecord::Base` and derive from that in all your models (probably doesn't work well with single-table inheritance):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => ["status = ?", "active"]
end
class ExampleModel < MyModel
end
```

...or you could set the `default_scope` on `ActiveRecord::Base` itself (could be annoying if you decide that one model should not have this default scope):

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => ["status = ?", "active"]
end
class ExampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

As mentioned by klochner in a comment, you may also want to consider adding a `named_scope` to `ActiveRecord::Base`, named `active`, for example:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :active, :conditions => ["status = ?", "active"]
end
class ExampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end
ExampleModel.active  # Return all active items.
```

Comment: how about a named scope on ActiveRecord::Base?  That would be less likely to confuse other developers if the project gets shared.

Comment: @klochner, yes, good point. Using something like ExampleModel.active is very expressive.

Comment: to clean it up a little more, you could derive a class from ActiveRecord that has the named (or new default) scope, and have ExampleModel derive from that.  Now the new functionality is explicit.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer. One more question though. How can I use this named route while still allowing for adding more conditions to the search?

Comment: @rube_noob: You can chain the named scopes (any number) and the regular find methods: ExampleModel.active.find(:conditions => ...).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** `named_scope` was [deprecated/renamed](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/named_scope) in Rails 3.1. As of 3.2.8, the new method is called `scope` which uses the `where` method instead of `:conditions`

Old:

```
named_scope :active, :conditions => ["status = ?", "active"]
```

New:

```
scope :active, where(:status => "active")
```

or

```
scope :active, where("status = ?", "active")
```