# How to automatically add extra condition to all Models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm now come to the condition which I need to add some default extra rule to Rails.

eg. when I call :
      Person.first 
      Employee.all 
    It will automatically do: 
      Person.first(:conditions => ['age < ?', 100])
      Employee.all(:conditions => ['age < ?', 100])

In here the condition age < 100 is added to all Models including sub-resources, is there a way to do this in Rails?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326743/adding-find-condition-to-all-active-record-models-in-rails

Comment: I get some help from it, but I also want to have the default condition include when Update and Delete(fully CRUD).

Comment: Why do you need default condition when you update and delete?

Comment: In order to get better performance, because my table contains millions of records and still growing steadily.

Answer (score 0):

you may use default_scope like the following

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => ['age < ?', 100]
end
```

You might be interested in this post.

http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using default scope for conditions, just for ordering.

So I would add a named scope in each model and then use that scope for most queries, e.g.

### Rails 3

```
scope :confirmed, :conditions => { 'age < ?',100 }
```

### Rails 4

*Some scopes are moving to be class methods (what they basically are anyway) so you can use something like:*

```
def age_limit
  where :age < 100
end
```

More info on using scopes at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5609947/631619

Having the same code in more than model is somewhat undry but this is the routes I would take for less than a dozen models.  You could also create a Constant AGE_LIMIT but then system constant are fraught with issues.  You might be better of creating a model perhaps just for age, then have a model for max_age, then refer to that. Something like that.